# Is it possible to sell all items with given costs to people with given amount of money

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, max-flow

Recently I ran into a real problem, which I can refolmulate as the following algorithmic task:

**Problem:** 
Given a set of `N` persons, each having some amount of money, and a set of `M` items, each having some cost, is it possible to sell all of the items?

Each item should be bought by at most one person, each person can buy multiple items so that their cost does not exceed the amount of money he has.

**My attempted solution:**
I was thinking in the direction of constructing a network and finding a maximal flow like this: 
- Make a bipartide graph with vertexes in one part corresponding to persons, and in other part - to items.
- Connect persons to source `S` and set the edge capacities to money people have.
- Connect items to sink `T` and set the edge capacities to the item costs. 
- Connect each person to the items he can buy and set edge capacities to the item costs

In case each edge in the maximal flow found in this network is either empty or fully saturated, the problem will be solved by looking if all edges going to `T` are saturated, and if we want to know who should buy what item we would look at the edges between left and right parts.

However but the problem is that the resulting flow can contain partially filled edges (meaning that a person partially paid for some item), and this case I am unable to eliminate.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a kind of [Bin Packing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

Also see [Multiple knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multiple_knapsack_problem).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple knapsack would solve this problem accurately but definitely it is an overkill as all elements have the same weight (which is value from the knapsack's perspective).

My intuition suggests using a greedy algorithm when in every iteration you try to sell the most expensive item to the poorest person at the moment who can still afford it. It is based on conviction that if you cannot sell an item before selling cheaper ones you will not sell it at all. Additionally exhausting budget of poorer buyers first will leave the others with more power to buy more expensive items. I suppose you have enough test data to verify it.